# Android Image Crop: Output x and Output y

Tags: android, crop

I have implemented image crop intent with a specific output size. But changes done in the sizes on code doesn't effect in any way to the image and the output for each change remains the same.

```
 private void performCrop(String picUri) {
    try {
        //Start Crop Activity

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        // indicate image type and Uri
        File f = new File(picUri);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

        cropIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
        // set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        // indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        // indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 400);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 400);

        // retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, RESULT_CROP);
    }
    // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        // display an error message
        String errorMessage = "your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Changes in the output x and y value doesn't effect the image size being cropped. Image size always remains 160*160. Jut when I change the aspect ratio the image size changes a bit. But i need to provide a specific size for x and y

And if there be any library regarding image crop and also supported on all device then it would awesome

Comment: Why dont you just set your imageview to the dimensions you want and set  scaletype=centercrop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the aspectX and aspectY in ratio of outputX and outputY.

Suppose you want the result image as 200 * 300 pixels. Then, simply set aspectX as 2 and aspectY as 3. You'll get the desired image dimension. Here is the updated code.

```
 private void performCrop(String picUri) {
    try {
        //Start Crop Activity

        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        // indicate image type and Uri
        File f = new File(picUri);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);

        cropIntent.setDataAndType(contentUri, "image/*");
        // set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        // indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 2);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 3);
        // indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 300);

        // retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        // start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, RESULT_CROP);
    }
    // respond to users whose devices do not support the crop action
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
        // display an error message
        String errorMessage = "your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
    }
```